# Prettyfaces url style search gmail

Tags: jsf, search, encoding, gmail, prettyfaces

Good day:

I am conducting a search using prettyFaces, style gmail.
When I do with gmail, space is replaced by a symbol "+". And in the box is not added the "+".

[image: Example Gmail]

In my case, when I do the same, in other characters url as in my box are added.

[image: My app]

Here the mapping code, and box:

```
<url-mapping id="search">
    <pattern value="/buscar/#{ /.*/ searchBean.q}" />
    <view-id value="/faces/reqs/search.xhtml" />
    <action>#{searchBean.search}</action>
</url-mapping>

<div class="search">
    <h:form id="searchForm">
        <span class="button-group">
           <p:inputText value="#{searchBean.q}" size="50"/>
           <p:commandButton action="pretty:search"/>
        </span>
     </h:form>
 </div>
```

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

And if facebook would be because it is a parameter? and as it would be a solution to avoid aparesca special characters in the input?
[image: facebook example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. In case of GMail the spaces are part of the "fragment" which is the part after the "#" character. In your PrettyFaces setup, the search term is part of the path.

There are different encoding rules for fragments and path parts of the URL. So PrettyFaces is handling this correctly.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.